# how do you pass a json.loads object from flask to jinja without it being truncated?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my app.py file, I build a query from form fields in Flask, query an API and get a json response (list of dicts), use json.loads and render that list to the template. The query is building fine (passing and printing query to debug), the list structure looks fine (printing out to debug), but my app.py function seems to be only building and rendering the first record in the list to the template. Outside of Flask/Jinja the same basic code works fine (returns all records). Using the exact same query being built in Postman returns all the records. Not sure if it's a Flask scoping issue, or security thing, but if so why would it build the first response?

```
app.py
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def formCat():
    form = searchForm()
    results = []
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        r = requests.get(URL_query)
        if(r.ok):
            results = json.loads(r.content)['results']
    return render_template('myForm.html', form=form, results=results)

myForm.html
{% extends "formTestBase.html" %}

{% block research %}
{% for x in results %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {% if 'company' in x %}
                                {{ x['company'] }}
                            {% else %}
                                No Value
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>                            
                        <td>
                            {% if 'product' in x %}
                                {{ x['product'][0]['code'] }}
                            {% else %}
                                No Value
                            {% endif %}
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            {% if 'brand' in x %}
                                {{ x['brand'][0]['brands'] }}
                            {% else %}
                                No Value
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

No errors in the code, but I am only getting the first record returned from the call in app.py and the same query in Postman gives me however many I set 'Limit' to. Incomplete sample of data that is returned from API call:

```
Results = [{'has_id_number': 'false', 'mri_safety': 'contains Information', 'record_status': 'Published', 'is_r': 'true', 'is_labeled': 'false', 'dis_status': 'In Commercial Distribution', 'device_description': 'Brigham End, 2.2mm Wide, 1x2 Teeth', 'public_device_record_key': '31feddb2-6ea4-4c98-bc66-0a3c583c89b1', 'has_serial_number': 'false', 'public_version_date': '2019-08-21', 'sterilization': {'sterilization_methods': 'Moist Heat or Steam Sterilization', 'is_sterilization_prior_use': 'true', 'is_sterile': 'false'}, 'is_direct_marking_exempt': 'false', 'is_labeled_as_no_nrl': 'false', 'public_version_number': '5', 'labeler_duns_number': '04', 'identifiers': [{'issuing_agency': 'HC', 'id': 'M2741302871', 'type': 'Secondary'}, {'issuing_agency': 'GS1', 'id': '10381780433293', 'type': 'Primary'}], ...
```

Comment: with your code sample, we are unable to see your full `myForm.html` file, so we aren't going to be able to help you identify the source of your problem. there is more than likely something wrong in your JINJA template. are you sure you are closing out your `{% for x in results %}` loop with an `{% endfor %}` statement?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I added in the extends, block, and endfor  tags above as they are in my code - obviously the indents are way off in the example but all are good in my code. I have tried several different approaches and the only reason I was thinking that the issue is not with the html page is because when i print out the variable (still inside the template but out of the html) I get the 'results' object with the first record. Maybe a red herring.

Comment: since your example of the `results` from the API call is, in itself, incomplete, this would error out before even being returned. was that just what you copy/pasted from your IDE? because a lof of IDE's will truncate the response when trying to display it. after `results = json.loads(r.content)['results']`, can you put in `print(len(results))` to see how many actual results are being returned? if this is more than 1, then the issue is definitely in the JINJA template, but there still isn't a complete example of the table you are trying to parse it into.

Comment: len(results) = 1 in the template. I am printing out the whole object in the template as well so I could see previously that it was only returning 1 record. From the command line I have also piped the [results] to a text file and can grep the record count which is more than 1. And I have taken the same code out of Flask/Jinja and run it at the command line and returns len which equals what I set the 'limit' value to be (e.g. http://.....&Limit=4) when I make the call to the API.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this is happening, or why this worked, but I ended up making two completely separate functions out of URL_query() and results() and put them outside the existing app.py with form class and imported them. I tried both approaches with old and a new venv and reproduced the results (old approach did not work in either, new approach worked in both).
@crookedleaf, thanks for your help.